# How to find the condition number of a matrix using Mathematica v9.0?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I'm new to Mathematica and therefore I apologize for my easy question below.

I would like to determine the condition number of a matrix and searched the net and found a command which is as:

```
LinearAlgebra`MatrixConditionNumber[mat]
```

However, I don't have a package LinearAlgebra. Where could I find this package and does this package work with v9 ? I also don't know where to load this package in my computer.

I only know is I will use `` Needs[Package Name`] `` in Mathematica?

Could you help me with this issue?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think MMA version 9 has `SingularValuList`. Well then, the condition number is the ratio of the largest to smallest singular value.